# Using hibernate 6.0.10 validation results in ConstraintDefinitionException from EachPattern

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-boot

When I try to use an `@EachPattern` on a List with:

```
@EachPattern(
   regexp = "^[a-z]+",
   message = "Invalid"
)
public List<String> getTestItems()
{
    return Arrays.asList( "aaaaa" );
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintDefinitionException: HV000243: Constraint cz.jirutka.validator.collection.constraints.EachPattern references constraint validator type cz.jirutka.validator.collection.CommonEachValidator, but this validator is defined for constraint type java.lang.annotation.Annotation.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor.of(ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorDescriptor.forClass(ConstraintValidatorDescriptor.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.lambda$getDefaultValidatorDescriptors$6(ConstraintHelper.java:1001)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.getDefaultValidatorDescriptors(ConstraintHelper.java:1002)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.lambda$getAllValidatorDescriptors$2(ConstraintHelper.java:730)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper$ValidatorDescriptorMap.computeIfAbsent(ConstraintHelper.java:1043)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper$ValidatorDescriptorMap.access$100(ConstraintHelper.java:1033)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.getAllValidatorDescriptors(ConstraintHelper.java:730)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.findValidatorDescriptors(ConstraintHelper.java:744)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.assertValidationAppliesToParameterSetUpCorrectly(ConstraintHelper.java:923)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.lambda$isConstraintAnnotation$5(ConstraintHelper.java:864)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.isConstraintAnnotation(ConstraintHelper.java:860)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findConstraintAnnotations(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:507)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findConstraints(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:461)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findExecutableMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getMethodMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.retrieveBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.getBeanConfigurationForHierarchy(BeanMetaDataManager.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.createBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.lambda$getBeanMetaData$0(BeanMetaDataManager.java:160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.getBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.buildNewLocalExecutionContext(ValidatorImpl.java:749)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.access$200(ValidatorImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl$CascadingValueReceiver.doValidate(ValidatorImpl.java:681)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl$CascadingValueReceiver.indexedValue(ValidatorImpl.java:657)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ListValueExtractor.extractValues(ListValueExtractor.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ListValueExtractor.extractValues(ListValueExtractor.java:16)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ValueExtractorHelper.extractValues(ValueExtractorHelper.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedContainerElementsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:627)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraints(ValidatorImpl.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:389)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:169)
```

But the class that has the problem is not mine, it's the `@EachPattern` itself, which has: `@Constraint(validatedBy = CommonEachValidator.class)` and that class has `public class CommonEachValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Annotation, Collection<?>>` which seems to cause the issue.

I am using:

```
compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.12.Final")
compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.0.12.Final")
compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:6.0.10.Final")
compile("javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final")
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Just faced similar problem, did you solve it?

Comment: @streetturtle no i didn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With hibernate-validator 6.0.10 you transitively pull in the dependency to the Bean Validation API (javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final) which has new features, [including](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/) more flexible cascaded validation of container types, so basically you can **add validation annotations to elements of collections of type java.util.Iterable, java.util.List and java.util.Map**.

So you can remove `cz.jirutka.validator.collection.constraints.EachPattern` and instead use `javax.validation.constraints`' @Pattern following way:

```
public List<@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-z]+", message = "Invalid") String> getTestItems()
{
    return Arrays.asList( "aaaaa" );
}
```